# CloudFront image cache-control headers

Tags: header, amazon-s3, cache-control, amazon-cloudfront

1- Is this a valid cache control header:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=86400, s-maxage=3600
```

2- I am trying to set cache control headers for objects served from S3 through CloudFront. The images don't often change, but sometimes can. Does this seem like a good cache control for this? CloudFront should re-validate every 60 minutes, but the user will cache for a full day. (I'm less worried about an individual user and more worried about continuing to serve the stale image to new users).

3- Are there other headers I should use? (ie. proxy-revalidate)

Its not horrendously easy to change these settings on S3 objects so I'm trying to get it right the first time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just made it working with both

1. Access-control-Max-Age (Set in S3 CORs setting)
2. Cache-control
3. expires

In theory and from AWS S3 / Cloudfront doc, only 1. will works. In practice, it takes both.

Keith

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I got to work:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=29030400, public
Expires: Wed, 30 Dec 2015 18:00:00 GMT
```

In theory, you only need one or the other. But this whole browser caching thing with S3 and CloudFront has been a big pain in my backside, so I like to keep them both in there. And I also put the following in my `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN Caching
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# END Caching
```